Blending new 2 1/4 oak flooring with 20+ y/o oak flooring
I’m installing 2 1/4” oak flooring in the kitchen.  It will have to blend in with the dining room flooring and line up parallel to the family room.
I’ve already removed the necessary dining room flooring so I can blend in the new.
What I’ve run into, is that the new flooring is 1/32” wider. I can pound the new flooring in, but 8 boards in, it’s impossible.  The gap is now 1/4”!
The new flooring is from “First Atlanta Flooring” in Atlanta.  It says Bluegrass Wood Product Made in USA.


Please describe in detail how the planks are oriented in both the family and dining room. If you are adding flooring, why is the dimensioning of the new flooring a problem?

Facing south, the family room is to the left and spans part of the kitchen, (separated by a wall and doorway) and the entire dining room.  In fact, the family room to dining room has an opening of 10’ or so.  The family room and dining room floor flow as one in an L shape.  Upside down L if facing south.  So both rooms have access to the kitchen via 32” doorways.  Coming off the family room to the kitchen, the flooring is parallel.  From the dining room, it’s a linear continuation.

I was hoping to add more pictures originally, but I could only seem to get one. I don’t see how to add additional pictures at this time.

While not an answer to your problem, I did something similar.  Had to tie in and match 60 year old oak strip (2-1/4" wide) with new unfinished material from a lumber store.  Fit right in with no issues.  I was having the floors refinished at the same time so I wasn't concerned about matching shade.

Without knowing more about your layout I can't say for sure what to do in your situation.  However, we had a similar situation when we tore out some old linoleum and laminate flooring to replace with oak hardwood to harmonize/match other areas of our house that already had beautiful oak hardwood floors that had been there for 25 years or so.  Since we weren't sure the widths would be identical between our old flooring and the new, we asked our professional flooring installer to install a couple strips of hardwood flooring crosswise at the room transition to help define the room transition and to mask any slight width differences between the old and new.  This way, we didn't need to try and exactly match up the width of the old floor vs new, and didn't need to get the new flooring lining up exactly with the old.  Our installer did a great job matching it after all, but if it's not too late, I might suggest doing something like this to make your life easier.


In retrospect, I wish I’d dive this.  But I’ve already removed pieces of the old floor.

Can’t edit comment, dive = done.

@Number4 - You can always delete a  comment.  Then create a new one with the spelling corrected.

I think I understand what you men by the gap. Whenever you are dealing with 2 different sizes of material like this, it will "run ahead" of the original. The only way I se to fix it is, where you need to run the new material in the same line as the original you will need to narrow down the few pieces that meet up with the original, for that whole run, until the new material goes from wall to wall with no tieing into the original anymore.
A table saw will be handy here, which while running floor, you should have one handy already. You may need to only cut the width without redoing the groove. Try a scrap piece, to see what you need to do. It may work out so you do not have to recut the groove. If you do, that will be really tedious, almost worth getting a router with a 1/4" rabbeting bit, with bearing guide.

I’m beginning to wonder if the new floor hasn’t acclimated to the room yet.  My wife was would not let me bring stacks into the house so it’s been in the garage.  Only two days in the house.
My goal, prior to this thought, was to trim 3 rows as needed to get me past the door way opening.

If it has not acclimated, that may the the issue. It may take up to 2 weeks to get it down to the proper moisture content (MC). The material should a dead on accurate 2 1/4". Gang 4 or 5 pcs together to see what the number adds up to. When it is nailed it will draw much tighter than just putting them together, but is still should measure to be a  2 1/4" multiple. 9", 11 1/4", 13 1/2" and so on. By the way, during the summer, unless you have AC, it may be hard to get the MC down.
